# AWS ELB Health Check for MongoDB container fails

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to use a mongoDB container on Amazon ECS and I want to set up a load balancer with a healthcheck that pings port 27017

What I've done:

1. Double checked all my security groups to make sure everything has access to port 27017
2. The load balancer has a health check set to TCP:27017
3. My ECS service is set up to identify the ELB and seems to be correctly mapped to the contianerName and port correctly.

It still fails every time. I can't even figure out how to debug this problem. When I run the container locally I can `nc localhost 27017` and it "seems" to connect (well, I get a blank line which I don't get with any other port)

How can I health check my mongodb?

### Update 1:

output of `netstat -tulpn | grep 27017`

```
tcp        0      0 :::27017    :::*     LISTEN      2600/docker-proxy
```

#### Update 2:

My health check settings are as follows:

```
Ping Target TCP:27017
Timeout 10 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 5
Healthy threshold   10
```

Comment: Is this port open in your Instance security group 27017?

Comment: Yes. I am able to see and connect to it from the public IP address of the EC2 machine.

Comment: Can you paste output of netstat -tulpn | grep :27017 on your EC2?

Comment: Sure. Added above.

Comment: And what is the timeout period you have specified in the health check?

Comment: I just used the defaults (updated above). 10 seconds should be more than enough time on the same network no?

Comment: Try 2 things change that port to 80 and see if it passes health check before that first try increasing the timeout to 30 Sec and try if it passes the health check.

Comment: I tried both those things and I still have no healthy hosts.

Comment: Is your load balancer in VPC or a EC2 classic?

Comment: It's VPC. Everything else about my VPC seems to be working.

Comment: Can you check the Security group attached to the Load Balncer if that port is open there?

Comment: The port is exposed and open.

Comment: This is a very common problem as it is a infrastructure as a code. There have been cases where everything is well configured but the ELB behaves weird, I would suggest you to create another ELB and try.

Comment: I tried recreating ELB but that didn't work. I really wish I had more visibility or logging with the ELB healthcheck. I can't figure out where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a configuration issue on your part.

If the ELB is public then you need to make sure the security groups for your instances allow it to talk to it publicly.

If the ELB is internal then you need to make sure the security groups allow them to talk to each other, such as putting them in the same security group.

You also need to make sure you've forwarded the port to the ECS instance so that it's reachable. Make sure you can hit the service *on the ecs instance* from a different server, whether at AWS or your laptop.

What do your security groups look like? What does your configuration look like? Are the instances private? public? Is the ELB private? public?

Comment: The issue was that the healthcheck port was in the securitygroup but not set up as an ELB listener.

Comment: I also ran into this problem and figured out the same solution. However then I discovered that ELB security group is not updated with the dynamic ports of the containers. Did you guys ran into that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832433/dynamic-ports-and-aws-applocation-load-balancer-and-ecs

Comment: Security groups are never "modified", it's up to you to know during creation. I'll add details in your question